# Issues with opening a python file in a separate window from another python file

Tags: python, file, console

I need to open hello.py file in a new console window from another python file basemain.py

I need the hello.py file to pop open in a new python console. I am not just trying to read, run or execute the file. I know I can manually open the file with ctrl+o and open it in separate window but I am trying to use code instead of me using ctrl+o every single time.

I have already tried
1)

```
from subprocess import Popen

#Popen(['python3', 'C:\\Users\\sammy\\Desktop\\project\\hello.py'], shell=True)
```

did not work. I just saw a glimpse of command promt for 1 second then it went away. I did not see file popped up in a separate console

2)

```
open('C:/Users/sammy/Desktop/project/hello.py',"r")
```

also didn't work. I am guessing the file is being read but I need to see it popped up in a separate console. that didn't happen

3)

```
import os
webbrowser.open('hello.py')
```

just opened the internet browser. nothing else happened

4)

```
os.system("hello.py")
```

again, same thing as 1)

5)

```
import os

os.startfile('hello.py')
```

again, same thing as 1)

6)

```
import webbrowser
import os

webbrowser.open(os.getcwd() + "C:/Users/sammy/Desktop/project/hello.py")
```

again, just opened internet browser. nothing else

These are the solutions I found in other questions in stackoverflow and in other forums. none of them are making a separate console to be popped up so that I can see and edit the file and then run. some of them are just reading the file but I cannot see the file

I am using python 3.10 in Windows 10 system

I am fairly new in python, so if anyone can help, I greatly appreciate that. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try executing `cmd /k python hello.py`.

Comment: Are you trying to open it with the builtin IDLE? or in a different editor?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: as I know console may not have function to run code and later display prompt to edit it. It can only open window, run code and later close it.